# Java | Use constant and check if a value equals one of them

Tags: java, constants

I have this class to hold my constants:

```
public class UserRole {
    static final String ADMIN = "Admin";
    static final String SELLER = "Seller";
    static final String BIDDER = "Bidder"; 
}
```

When Im getting input from the user I want to check that `input.toLower()` equals to one of this constants.
 (I want the class to provide such a method)
I can do it with multiple `if`s of course but i want it to be more elegant. I gonna use a lot of constants in my code and that w'd probably produce a more elegant code that easier to debug and read.
Im coming from the C++ world where i can use x-macros or something similar and i'd like to know what is a good way to achieve this task in Java.

Comment: put them in a List and use contains: `Arrays.asList(UserRole.ADMIN, UserRole.SELLER, UserRole.BIGGER).contains(input)` - Note however that I see huge problems with your plan on checking if `input.toLower()` (which i assume means the lowercase conversion of your input) equals a couple of Strings of which not a single one is all lower case.

Comment: A `Set` would be a bit more efficient if there are many roles. With three roles, a `List` (as @OHGODSPIDERS suggested) is fine, and may even be more efficient (I'm not sure).

Comment: sounds like an ideal use case for an `enum` since you can iterate over the constants and compare their names.

Comment: @pasta64 how would `eval()` work for this question?

Comment: `enum` (`String`s are not type safe) then `UserRole.valueOf(u.toUpperCase());` An exception will be thrown if not valid.

Comment: `boolean matches = switch(input.toLower()) { case ADMIN, SELLER, BIDDER -> true; default -> false; };` but as @OHGODSPIDERS already said, there will never be a match as long as your constant strings contain uppercase characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Enum

> I gonna use a lot of constants in my code and that w'd probably produce a more elegant code that easier to debug and read.

For constants known at compile time, an [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html) is often the best approach. The enum facility in Java is more powerful and flexible than you may have seen in other languages.

In Java, each enum object is named in all-uppercase, by convention.

```java
enum UserRole
{
    ADMIN ,
    SELLER , 
    BIDDER ;
 }
```

Fetch by constant name.

```java
UserRole userRole = UserRole.valueOf( UserRole.class , "seller".toUpperCase() ) ;
```

See that [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/452Z2R).

> userRole.toString() = SELLER

Or, you may want to add a display name for presentation to the users.

Add a private member field to the enum class. Write a constructor that takes the text of each enum object’s display name. Add a getter method. And write a `static` method to look for the enum matching an expected display name.

```java
enum UserRole
{
    ADMIN ( "Admin" ) ,
    SELLER ( "Seller" ) , 
    BIDDER ( "Bidder" ) ;

    private final String displayName ;

    // Constructor 
    UserRole ( String displayName ) 
    {
        this.displayName = displayName ;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() 
    { 
        return this.displayName ; 
    }

    public static UserRole forDisplayNameIgnoreCase ( final String desiredDisplayName ) 
    {
        for ( UserRole userRole : UserRole.values() )
        {
            if ( userRole.getDisplayName().equalsIgnoreCase( desiredDisplayName ) )
            {
                return userRole ;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Unknown display name" ) ;  // Or return an `Optional< UserRole >`. The Optional would be my preference. 
    }

}
```

Fetch by display name.

```
UserRole userRole = UserRole.forDisplayNameIgnoreCase ( "seller" ) ;
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/OGBpRo).

> userRole.toString() = SELLER

Comment: Enum is best approach when it can be used, it has issues - it doesn't support inheritance, if you have values attached to enum you cannot use them in places which require constants (some annotations) and then you need an annotation processor to turn them into constants.
I wouldn't assume that person asking didn't consider using enums already.

Comment: @MajaStamenic  Inheritance, attached values, and annotations are issues not mentioned nor implied by the Question. As for the person asking already considering enums — apparently not, as they have accepted this Answer (notice the green checkmark).

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to match the input against the constants fields. You could use map to match such data. However, still if you want to do it, here is the class.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class ConstantCheckerUtil {
    public static boolean checkConstant(String input) {
        boolean hasAnyMatch = false;

        try {
            Class<UserRole> userRoleClass = UserRole.class;
            Field[] userRoleClassDeclaredFields = userRoleClass.getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field userRoleClassDeclaredField : userRoleClassDeclaredFields) {
                if(userRoleClassDeclaredField.get(userRoleClassDeclaredField.toString()).toString().toLowerCase().equals(input)) {
                    hasAnyMatch = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); //You can enhance the logging part
        }

        return hasAnyMatch;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { //Testing
        System.out.println(ConstantCheckerUtil.checkConstant("Admin".toLowerCase()));
    }
}
```